# PL/SQL UPDATE -- Well, not updating

Tags: plsql, sql-update

I am using a procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_rec(
    page_id   IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_ID_NBR%TYPE,
    page_type IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_Type%TYPE,
    page_dcpn IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_Dcpn%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE SSC_Page_Map
  SET Page_Type     = page_type,
    Page_Dcpn       = page_dcpn
  WHERE Page_ID_NBR = page_id;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

to update my database table row.  I confirm the procedure execute correctly but I don't see the update.  I have commented out the update to confirm I have permission to modify the database and that succeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SET Page_Type = page_type` updates the column with the current column value.

The visibility rules inside a PL/SQL program are such that the column name takes precedence over your parameter name. Give your parameters a different name and everything should be fine. A common coding convention is to prepend the parameters with `p_` to identify them as parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_rec(p_page_id IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_ID_NBR%TYPE, 
                                       p_page_type IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_Type%TYPE, 
                                       p_page_dcpn IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_Dcpn%TYPE)

IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE SSC_Page_Map 
       SET Page_Type = p_page_type, 
           Page_Dcpn = p_page_dcpn 
   WHERE Page_ID_NBR = p_page_id;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Genius!  Thank you for such a simple but elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases for zero ambiguity:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_rec(
  page_id   IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_ID_NBR%TYPE,
  page_type IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_Type%TYPE,
  page_dcpn IN SSC_Page_Map.Page_Dcpn%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE SSC_Page_Map
  SET Page_Type     = update_rec.page_type,
    Page_Dcpn       = update_rec.page_dcpn
  WHERE SSC_Page_Map.Page_ID_NBR = update_rec.page_id;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

(Note: I have seen one case where someone added a column called something like `p_xyz` to a table, which caused no end of trouble for the client whose naming convention had `p_` for all procedure/function parameters. The alias method, in contrast, works 100% of the time.)